# Rewrite Methodreference in particular package only using dexlib2

Tags: android, dex, smali

I am using dexlib2 for rewriting dex files. I need to replace particular class name with my library class name which I will include in aar. I am using below code for it:

```
    DexFile dexFile = DexFileFactory.loadDexFile(filePath, Opcodes.forApi(apiLevel));
        DexRewriter dexRewriter = new DexRewriter(new RewriterModule() {

            @Override
            public Rewriter<MethodReference> getMethodReferenceRewriter(Rewriters rewriters) {
                return new Rewriter<MethodReference>() {
                    @Override
                    public MethodReference rewrite(MethodReference value) {

                        if (value.getDefiningClass().equals("Ljava/util/Calendar;")
                                && value.getName().equals("getInstance")) {
                            System.out.println("method Ref class:" + value.getDefiningClass());

                            ImmutableMethodReference methodRef = new ImmutableMethodReference(
                                    "Lcom/mylib/ICalendar;", value.getName(),
                                    value.getParameterTypes(), value.getReturnType());
                            return methodRef;
                        }
                        return value;
                    }
                };
            }

        });
        DexFile rewrittenDexFile = dexRewriter.rewriteDexFile(dexFile);
        DexFileFactory.writeDexFile(filePath, rewrittenDexFile);
```

But with this one, It will replace this class in all other libraries also which will cause issue. I want it to be replaced only if it has in classes with certain packages. can I add that kind of filter on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can override getClassDefRewriter and add your filter there.

```
DexRewriter dexRewriter = new DexRewriter(new RewriterModule() {

    @Nonnull @Override public Rewriter<ClassDef> getClassDefRewriter(@Nonnull Rewriters rewriters) {
        return new ClassDefRewriter(rewriters) {
            @Nonnull @Override public ClassDef rewrite(@Nonnull ClassDef classDef) {
                if (classDef.getType().startsWith("Lcom/my/package/")) {
                    return super.rewrite(classDef);
                }
                return classDef;
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public Rewriter<MethodReference> getMethodReferenceRewriter(Rewriters rewriters) {
        return new Rewriter<MethodReference>() {
            @Override
            public MethodReference rewrite(MethodReference value) {

                if (value.getDefiningClass().equals("Ljava/util/Calendar;")
                        && value.getName().equals("getInstance")) {
                    System.out.println("method Ref class:" + value.getDefiningClass());

                    ImmutableMethodReference methodRef = new ImmutableMethodReference(
                            "Lcom/mylib/ICalendar;", value.getName(),
                            value.getParameterTypes(), value.getReturnType());
                    return methodRef;
                }
                return value;
            }
        };
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response Again! I have used it. I am facing issue after updating dex file. To validate, I have tried to convert it in jar using dex2jar and it is giving error while converting (d2j fail translate: java.lang.RuntimeException: \r\n\tat com.googlecode.dex2jar.ir.ts.NewTransformer.transform(NewTransformer.java:134))

Comment: Dunno. Sounds like a problem with dex2jar :)

Comment: I am able to use it. but After replacing one of class name using getTypeRewriter, my apk crashes. Saying NoSuchMethodError. Basically I have created one library which is added as aar which has actual class for which I have changed type.

Comment: Well, does the method that it throws the error for exist? :)

Comment: I have one class Say IDate which extends Date and  I have replaced type Date with IDate. I am getting error when code has simpleDateFormat.format(IDate);. I have tried in code manually. It is allowed but when used in dex file. It is throwing error.

Comment: If you're invoking a method on an interface, you have to use invoke-interface, not invoke-virtual.

Comment: SimpleDateFormat is android SimpleDateFormat class so its not interface. only thing I can doubt is like I am updating dex with my custom class which is not there yet. but after updating dex, I am merging my library which has that class . so could it be issue?